# using encrypted password from config.ini file and decrypt it to be used in the main script

Tags: python-3.x, cryptography, fernet

I have a general question. My code is running fine and there are no errors. My question is I have written the key and the encrypted password in the configfile like below:

```
[credentials]
key = d25vYTghWVgkTQWrMFnwW1tfKtn_lWzDr2JJM95f2fs=
encrypted_password = gAAAAABkLyRCekwyD5p5MMmaNxee6quDhlv9zx5e6Qghfv6jjubsGtP5m5F8YaB1LEPBq90-ab1VxK5oqOHmNStNbulSBMCtXQ==
```

Now I am deriving the key and encrypted password from config file and decrypting the password.
I know this is not the right way anyone can use the key and decrypt the password.
Is there anyway that without exposing the key I can decrypt the password.

Comment: Why would your code even have a password in the first place? Passwords are things users have.

Comment: If your program has access to a key, then anyone who can read your program can also access the key. This is a fundamental fact of programs that run on general-purpose hardware. If you have specialized hardware (for example, an [HSM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_security_module)) that you can require is attached to the machine that runs the program, then you can improve the protection of keys (though there are still limitations even with that setup if users can run arbitrary code). But any mechanism you use to access the key by the script can be used by anyone who reads the script.

Comment: This is a brocade switch. For which user login and password is required. I saw 2 ways on internet one is to write the key in different file and access it and other is os.environ. is there a way I can atleast restrict anyone from reading the script altogether. This script will run on schedule basis via windows scheduler.